# How do I create a list of quotes in my html from javascript objects?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, object, dynamic

*A Jsfiddle would be appreciated, thanks!

This is a sample of what I've been given in a js document:

```
    var comments = [
        {"name":"John","comment":"Text","timestamp":69379200},
        {"name":"Ronny","comment":"Text","timestamp":1007683200},
        {"name":"Darrel","comment":"Text","timestamp":172281600}
    ];
```

How do I load that into my preexisting unordered list as list items? Ideally in this sort of a format (including turning the unix timestamps into this format):

```
    <ul class="testimonials">
        <li>
            <blockquote>"Text"</blockquote>
            <cite>-John, 8/23/2014</cite>
        </li>
        <li>
            <blockquote>"Text"</blockquote>
            <cite>-Ronny, 8/23/2014</cite>
        </li>
        <li>
            <blockquote>"Text"</blockquote>
            <cite>-Darrel, 8/23/2014</cite>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

I'm new to loading javascript into my html, so if anyone can help me out and explain, I'd really appreciate it! Thanks!

Comment: "a fiddle would be appreciated".......you're right, it would....FROM you. Show us what you've tried.

Comment: Pretty simple once you figure it out. I would use jquery. Should be something like <script>$("ul#testimonials).append("<li><blockquote>"+comments[0].comment+"</blockquote><cite>-"+comments[0].name+", "+comments[0].timestamp+"</cite></li>);</script>
This should get you started, look at jquery and append. Try some stuff and good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
// the parent element
var ulElement = document.createElement("ul");
ulElement.setAttribute("class", "testimonials");

// iterate through the array
for ( var i = 0 ; i < comments.length ; i++ ) {

    // extract data from JavaScript
    var currentObj = comments[i];
    var currentName = currentObj.name;
    var currentComment = currentObj.comment;
    var currentTimestamp = currentObj.timestamp;

    // create child nodes for the parent        
    var liElement = document.createElement("li");
    // blockquote
    var blockquoteElement = document.createElement("blockquote");
    var t1 = document.createTextNode(currentComment);
    blockquoteElement.appendChild(t1);
    // cite
    var citeElement = document.createElement("cite");
    var d = new Date(currentTimestamp*1000);
    var formattedDate = d.getMonth()+ "/" + d.getDate() + "/" + d.getFullYear()
    var t2 = document.createTextNode(currentName + ", " + formattedDate);
    citeElement.appendChild(t2);
    // add children for li
    liElement.appendChild(blockquoteElement);
    liElement.appendChild(citeElement); 

    // add child nodes to parent   
    ulElement.appendChild(liElement); 
}
```

---

Here [you can see a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qjw7ke1p/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is something to get you started:

```
var comments = [
    {"name":"John","comment":"Text","timestamp":69379200},
    {"name":"Ronny","comment":"Text2","timestamp":1007683200},
    {"name":"Darrel","comment":"Text3","timestamp":172281600}
];

var feed = document.getElementById('feed'); // get our UL element

var output = "";                            // define output string variable

for (var i = 0; i < comments.length; i++) { // start the loop

    output += '<li><blockquote>' +          //
        comments[i].comment +               // build the output
        '</blockquote><cite>-' +            // on each iteration
        comments[i].name + ', ' +           // and append it
        comments[i].timestamp +             // to its previous value
        '</cite></li>';                     //
}

feed.innerHTML = output;                    // after the loop is done, 
                                            // set the contents of our UL
                                            // element to the output we just built
```

See it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/4aoh682q/1/

(note: I didn't convert the timestamp into formatted date)

Comment: Clean, separated approach. Optionally, DOM element appending can be used instead of string concatenation (to counter JayC's comment-answer)

Comment: @Tyblitz: reread my answer;  did I say anything that would imply DOM element appending cannot be used?  No.

Comment: @JayC: reread my comment, did I say anything that would imply you implied that? I was merely stating that a hybrid of Shomz & Curiosu's answer was possible (ie using DOM methods in the for loop, but keeping Shomz' more 'modular' approach)

Answer (score -1):

The simplest way is to use some templating framework like Mustache or even the simple mechanism Underscore.js uses and be done with it.

One big problem with Shomz's answer (as of this writing) is it doesn't handle html injection issues.

The answer from curiosu would seem to handle that from first reading but it could possibly be better; it's better to minimize interaction with the DOM to avoid causing issues with the rendering engine.  His doesn't necessarily do this―it is likely only a problem if the ul element has already been added.  But see how verbose this DOM code is?  Creating elements using the DOM apis can be quite useful, but writing the code is so tedious!

If you only need this functionality to create lists, it would actually be better *not* to use the templating framework as that code is just extra crap to bog down the page, but if you are using more than one list thing and you need extra flexibility to quickly modify what classes elements need, etc, it is hard to beat the usefulness of a templating framework.

Edit:

I will add that it's not hard to fix the encoding issues in Shomz's answer, and performance issues, if there are any, could be fixed by using an array, and joining afterwards.

Just add a proper `htmlEncode`

```
function htmlEncode( html ) {
    return document.createElement( 'a' ).appendChild( 
        document.createTextNode( html ) ).parentNode.innerHTML;
}
```

and then

```
var feed = document.getElementById('feed'); // get our UL element

var output = [];                            // define output string variable

for (var i = 0; i < comments.length; i++) { // start the loop

    output.push('<li><blockquote>' +           //
        htmlEncode(comments[i].comment) +      // build the output
        '</blockquote><cite>-' +               // on each iteration
        htmlEncode(comments[i].name) + ', ' +  // and append it
        comments[i].timestamp +                // to its previous value
        '</cite></li>');                        //
}

feed.innerHTML = output.join("");              // after the loop is done, 
                                               // set the contents of our UL
                                               // element to the output we just built
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4aoh682q/6/

Comment: I really don't know how that code I posted is a "big problem" since **everything** it does can be done via a console. Are consoles a new threat as well?

Comment: I don't understand why you're bringing consoles into this.  I mentioned html injection, much like SQL injection but only with html: http://xkcd.com/327/  .  Your code allows the html confines to be breached.

Comment: The second *problem* I avoided mentioning is that you are using `+=` to generate a potentially large string.  Please understand, for small lists, this isn't a problem, and may even be optimal.  But for large numbers of concatenations, it's certainly far from optimal.  http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/90203/why-is-so-bad-for-concatenation

Comment: I brought consoles in because if you can do HTML injection in the code I wrote, you can do it in anything that you can access with a console. I'm very well aware of what injections are... Not sure how you can touch the server with **anything** that's on there... About the concats, anything so big that would cause problems would also kill the browser/webpage since every byte is rendered on screen...

Comment: I'm curious now, show me the html injections using the code from my answer.

Comment: simplest case http://jsfiddle.net/4aoh682q/5/  ` {"name":"John","comment":"<Text","timestamp":69379200}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59867/discussion-between-jayc-and-shomz).

Comment: Yes, but that's exactly what you can do from the console, like I said... You can't modify the inputs coming from the server.